# PHP Settings? PHP not receiving POST data

Tags: post, php

I’m sending a .php file POST data from a java application. The .php file is not accepting the POST data. file_get_contents(‘php://input’) is empty and $_POST is empty. I know the problem isn’t with the .php file or java application because I tested it using a different host and it worked. Is there a setting in php.ini I’m missing or a setting I need to change?

Comment: Can you describe your server environment.

Comment: maybe you have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541362/php-loses-form-post-parameters

Comment: Check for max post size, and uploaded files in PHP appears in `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Comment: I have godaddy unlimited package.

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem too. For future visitors, my issue was missing the trailing slash in the url. Eg..

```
http://someplace.com/cheeseburger
```

should have been...

```
http://someplace.com/cheeseburger/
```

This was causing the post to fail, in my case.

Comment: How did you ever figure this out? I don't think I'd ever have figured this out!

Comment: How in the world did this work....thank goodness I found this suggestion...

Comment: Love You 3000...
I have been trying from months but couldn't find a solution. Today somehow I came through your answer, tried it, and it just worked.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Super thanks. You answer solved my problem.

Comment: OMG...Two days of pounding my head on my desk and it was this simple.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me from a headache! I didn't know there was such a difference between these, maybe at least on Apache.

Answer (score 16):

If the Content-Type is empty or not recognized in the HTTP message then the PHP $_POST array is empty. If you cannot send the Content-Type you can add this to your PHP:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
 $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
}
```

You can also check if you have the correct settings in your php.ini

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M
```

If post_max_size is 0, PHP will not populate $_POST.

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

If you do not have P in there, $_POST will not be set either.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I don't see how it could work on one host but not work on another. Godaddy is my host. It doesn't work on Godaddy, but it works perfectly fine on hosting24.com

Comment: The max size is 128M. P is in there.

Comment: Another idea would be doing a diff between the php.ini files of the two servers.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The problem was http:// and https://

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. It turned out to be because I was prefixing my target with http . I changed it to https and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was duplicate names for an input.

ex: 
/input name="test" type="text" /
/input name="test" type="text" /

each must have a different name
ex:
/input name="testA" type="text" /
/input name="testB" type="text" /

Answer (score 0):

My problem appeared out of nowhere.
I'm using an apache hack to hide the extension, so all I had to do is to remove .php from the file name and it worked.

```
/* from: */ action = "folder/filename.php"
/* to: */   action = "folder/filename"
```

I hope this answer helps someone else in the same situation