# I can't receive POST data in php with slim framework

Tags: php, rest, slim

I try to make a RESTful api using slim framework.
I do not know details  about the slim framework, because i'm beginner of this framework.
So, I followed all steps of how to get data in slimframework. But i can't get POST data.

---

### Follow is my code to get POST data.

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->post('/registration/user', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app) {
$data = $request->getParsedBody();
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo '1 : '.$data['name'];
echo '2 : '.$name;
});
```

---

### That is result of when i send name data.

[image]

what i have to do for get post data??
Do you have any idea?

Comment: have you configured your server to return you data?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon if you look in the picture you can see it returns `1: 2:`.

Comment: didn't see that, what are you expecting then?

Comment: what does your form look like?

Comment: @Johnmark can you `var_dump()`/`print_r()` `$_POST`?

Comment: Not sure you need that `use($app)` it shouldn't break anything but I am not sure

Comment: @TomUdding yes i did, but is returned empty array

Comment: this code is perfectly work.

           $app->get('/hello/{name}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    return $response->getBody()->write('Hello ~ '.$name);
});

Comment: @nerdlyist remove that, but sadly my problem is not solved

Comment: It does not appear your issue is with slim it seems that your `POST` data is not being sent. You make it into the route on post just no data is present. I do not know what would cause that. Can you attempt to just post to a php file and see if you can access the `$_POST` directly?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/6923687/2612651

Comment: Show example curl request with headers. Postman screenshots are not useful.

Comment: Have you bothered to learn what Content-Type is/does in the real world?

Answer (score 2):

I use \Slim\Http\Request `$request->getParsedBody()` in my routes. The method contains all the $_POST data.

Example:

```
$postArr  = $request->getParsedBody();
$name     = $postArr["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used:

```
$body= file_get_contents("php://input"); 
// $body = $request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($body, true);
```