# POST not working for HTML Form

Tags: php, html, post

I'm working on a registration page using an html form, however when I use post it doesn't submit the data. All this code is in the index.php file, so it directs to itself for the form action.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" style="align-content: left;text-align: center;padding:10px" id="signForm">
            Company: <input type="text" value="" name="company"><br>
            Email: <input style="margin-top:5px" type="text" value="" name="email"><br>
            Username: <input style="margin-top:5px" type="text" value="" name="username"><br>
            Password: <input style="margin-top:5px" type="password" value="" name="password"><br>
            Verify Password: <input style="margin-top:5px" type="password" value="" name="password2"><br>
            <input style="margin-top:10px" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitr">
        </form>
```

And here is the php, which is located above the form on the page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitr'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    ...
}
```

I've tried outputting the variables, however they are always blank, and I cannot seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is the form submitted normally, or with javascript?

Comment: Try [enabling error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/811240) and instead of `echo` use `var_dump()` to figure out what the variables contain.

Comment: @Mike the form is submitted normally, and when I use `var_dump($_POST);` in my code it outputs `array(0) { }` both before and after submitting the form.

Comment: Paste the entire index.php. $_POST shouldn't be empty...

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause that behaviour. Are you doing any rewriting with your .htaccess (or equivalent) files?

Comment: @Mike I'm using AWS for hosting/testing, so as far as I know I don't have access to a the .htaccess file.

Comment: @TurtleTread here is the complete file code [link](https://codedump.io/share/NRAHD7Hz8N4i/1/index)

Comment: @DanF Works fine for me.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923643/php-settings-php-not-receiving-post-data

Comment: So after looking through the link, I added the part about CONTENT-TYPE, and after looking at phpinfo, the other variables seem to be fine for my setup. I've gotten it to work, however it only works if `phpinfo();` is called, so that's some kind of progress.

Comment: Post the global.inc.php file content too please. ofc strip the sensitive data. Did you put session_start() before outputting any content body

Answer (score 1):

Try add a name to the form , also try add the enctype attribute in the form 
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)