# Passing variable from one page (with form) to another php

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a value from a select dropdown on an html form to another page after clicking a submit button. This value doesn't need to be stored in the database, but instead used temporary to display the users choice of product data from the database on the next page. The html output of the form works as expected with the value appearing in the option value, I just can't get it to post that value and "fetch" it from page two, I assume I am missing a step or doing it incorrectly, can anyone point me in the correct direction?:

Form showing on page 1:

```
<?php

echo '<form method="post" action="/page2">';
echo '<select name="selectProduct">';
echo '<option value="" disabled selected>--select--</option>';
foreach ( $getInfo as $product ) {
    echo '<option value="' . esc_html( $product->id ) . '">'.esc_html($product->product).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<div class="btnWrapper">';
    echo '<input class="btn border-width-0 btn-text-skin btn-color-jevc btn-square btn-icon-left adduserBtn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="View specs">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

Output on page2

```
<?php
// ...
$selectedProduct = $_POST['selectProduct'];
echo '<div><b>YOU SELECTED:</b>' . esc_html( $selectedProduct ) .'</div>';
```

When doing `var_dump($_POST);` on page2, I get an empty `array(0){}`

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` give you on page 2?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Hi, its a bit dangerous ADDING code to a question. You can  never be sure if you have not just gone and obfiscated the issue

Comment: i added <?php so the code would be readable

Comment: Yup, but even so, its a bad habit to start getting into :)

Comment: hence why i also added the `// ...` on his page 2, just in case he had code coming before before it

Comment: @delboy1978uk var dump on page two comes back empty with `array(0){}`

Comment: ok, so nothing got posted. can you open the network inspector in your browser? post the form and check the HTTP request params

Comment: Can be related : [PHP Settings? PHP not receiving POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923643/php-settings-php-not-receiving-post-data/51932476)

Comment: Just tried that but nothing seemed obvious, although just changed the method of page one and two to GET and two and for some reason that works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the method from post to GET resolved the issue.

Comment: Changing from POST to GET shouldn't have really fixed anything, and if this is a form that's going to be collecting a lot of data you should really go back to post. (Also advised for security purposes)

First thing I would suggest is doing `echo ($_POST) ? 'Post' : 'No Post'` and this will confirm if there for is actually being posted,

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I have tried changing back to post and it comes back with "No Post". However using GET seems to work. Not sure if it is relevant, but using Wordpress and connecting to a mySQL database.

Comment: @CloudTheWolf, The form isn't really collecting data at this point, all I am trying to do is get the id of the option chosen then when the submit button is clicked, redirect to a different page and display data based on that id that was chosen. 
Im getting this php error when it is posting:
WordPress database error Unknown column 'selectProduct' in 'field list' for query UPDATE `myDBtable` SET selectProduct= '39' WHERE id= 39
Any ideas?